# How to let scripts still work after refreshing a div on click?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am having a script, that inserts data into a database over ajax and after the insertion is done, a button appears to reload a div, which includes the inserted content. In the following my script to reload the div:

```
// RELOAD MAINCONTENT
$('#reload-maincontent').on("click", function(evt){
    var reloadContent = location.href + " #main--content";
    $("#main--content").load(reloadContent);
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

The content gets reloaded after I click it, but if I click buttons, that includes other scripts and which are included in the inserted data, those scripts doesn't work anymore, just after I reload the page completly. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
J LO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't attach an event handler to an element loaded by ajax because it appears on page after your script finish. You should use event bubbling like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", '#reload-maincontent', function(evt){
        var reloadContent = location.href + " #main--content";
        $("#main--content").load(reloadContent);
        evt.preventDefault();
  });
```